# absolute positioned li's height not working for responsive design

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I need to figure out how I'm going to show my content responsively. I'm using jQuery to slide in and out (horizontally) the li items, hence they are absolutely positioned. but some items have more text than others, and when I change screen size to simulate mobile devices, the absolutely positioned li's bleed down over the footer or just get clipped off at the bottom. If I use min-height, then I have to calculate the height needed based on the longest li. I'd rather not do that. Is there another way to build this page responsively and use absolutely positioned content? Even with jQuery, if I need to?

```
<div class="wrapper">
<ul class="container">
<li>… short copy</li>
<li>… long copy</li>
</ul>
<footer>…</footer>
</div>


.wrapper{
width:100%;
}
.container{
width:80%;margin:0 auto;position:relative;max-width:1280px;
}
li{
position:absolute;width:100%;
}
```

Comment: not 100% sure what you are trying to do, maybe add `overflow: hidden;` to `.container` css

Comment: Clarification: when the li's are made narrower (say on 480px w device), the text is longer and extends down the page more. When this happens,it overlaps the content below (and it's container), or if longer than the viewport, gets cut off. Make sense?

Comment: i understand now, let me think on that

Comment: have you tried setting the font-size to 1em ? Maybe it'll stop the text from expanding?

Comment: Setting the font-size doesn't affect it from overlapping or getting cutoff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to control the minimum height of the wrapper based on the screen width:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .wrapper {
    min-height: 600px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would help. I was looking for a way to not have to deal with setting min-height, but I may have to settle for that so my content doesn't come down too far. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's a way around that using pure css if you want the wrapper positioned absolutely. The normal flow has no way of knowing what the wrapper is doing. Up-votes are appreciated if the answer was helpful! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. The wrapper is not positioned absolutely though. I only have the li's positioned absolutely. I'd love to upvote you, but it seems I don't have that feature yet.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the li's were positioned absolutely; not the wrapper. My point was, the main content is being pulled out of the flow, so the container has nothing in it and no way of knowing what height it should be. With pure css, the only way to enforce any height on that container is to explicitly tell it. And if the main content's out-of-flow height is responding to its environment, than that container will have to be told to respond accordingly via height or min-height. And if you want it to change based on screen width, you'll need to use media queries (or js).